# How can I set an automated reply in Google Hangout?

Tags: google-hangouts

Google Hangout's [doesn't show](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/05/understanding-google-hangouts.html) if someone is online, so some of my contacts sometimes assume I'm online. How can I set an automated reply in Google Hangout like "I am not available on Hangout. Please send me an email instead."? I use [Gtalk Autoreply](http://gtalkautoreply.codeplex.com/) for Gtalk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use https://gchat.simon.codes to set up an automatic reply (disclosure: I made it) . It's intended for unused accounts though, so it might not be what you're looking for if you often log into the account.